# Get specific word before special character using regex

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I need to get the word before the special character in this case the **`** but it can be any special character. The string after the special character and the character should be ignored.

```
userTable` (`idUser`  int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,`userName` VARCHAR(50),`password` VARCHAR(25))
```

I was wondering if it could be easier to get the word using a regex that will ignore the special characters and the words after that.

Comment: Just use `\w+` to match

Comment: What words would you like to match?

Comment: I guess it will be something like `.replaceFirst("(?s).*?(\w+)\s*\`.*", "$1")` (if only the first one should be fetched).

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

```
(\w+)(?=[\'\"])
```

or

```
[\'\"]\K(\w+)
```

In [ ] just add any character you want but preceding with '\' f.e. \$ , \% etc. etc.

Comment: Java ICU-like regex does not support `\K`.